# Serializing datetime.date to JSON with javascript Date

Tags: javascript, python, json, datetime, serialization

How can I serialize a python list contains `datetime.date` objects, to a JSON array of javascript `Date` objects? For example:

```
lst = [datetime.date(2013, 12, 30), datetime.date(2013, 12, 31)]
print serialize(lst)
# should print "[new Date(2013, 12, 30), new Date(2013, 12, 31)]"
```

I've tried `json.dumps` with a custom handler but the handler can only return serializable objects and not the actual JSON syntax.

Comment: You can't have "...a JSON array of JavaScript `Date` objects." You can have a JSON array, *or* you can have a JavaScript array containing `Date` objects. [JSON](http://json.org/) != JavaScript, and JSON doesn't have any concept of dates.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the clarification, so how can I have a javascript array with Date objects?

Comment: basically, use `.isoformat()`. `Date` type is not supported in JSON.

Comment: @zsong thanks. It's not critical that the array will be JSON, javascript is ok as well. If i use .isoformat I will have to do another pass on the array in javascript to convert the values to `Date` objects and that's something I prefer not to do.

Comment: @Tzach You have to do that anyway coz JSON doesn't support Date type.

Comment: Watch out - when you use `new Date(...)` in JavaScript, the months range 0-11.  In python they are 1-12.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript `Date` objects are json-serialized to strings.  However, you can construct a date object from this serialized string.  The closest string that the python `datetime.date` class provides seems to be `isoformat`.

```
lst = [datetime.date(2013, 12, 30).isoformat(),
    datetime.date(2013, 12, 31).isoformat()]
```

On the JavaScript side, these will simply be strings like `"2013-12-31"`.  You can construct a date object from that -- `new Date("2013-12-30")`.  It will probably look something like:

```
lst = JSON.parse(lstJson);
lst.forEach(function (date) {
    var date = new Date(date);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do all of that directly in python?

Comment: @Tzach do *what*?  You can't store JavaScript date objects themselves in JSON.  They are serialized to the representative strings.

Comment: I doesn't really matter if the array is JSON or javascript, all I need is an output string that looks like the one in the question, so I can embed it into an existing JS code, without iterating over the array in JS.